# find mean position and area of labelled objects

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, iteration, labeling

I have a 2D labeled image (numpy array), each label represents an object. I have to find the object's center and its area. My current solution:

```
centers = [np.mean(np.where(label_2d == i),1) for i in range(1,num_obj+1)]

surface_area = np.array([np.sum(label_2d == i) for i in range(1,num_obj+1)])
```

Note that `label_2d` used for centers is not the same as the one for surface area, so I can't combine both operations. My current code is about 10-100 times to slow.

In C++ I would iterate through the image *once* (2 for loops) and fill the table (an array), from which I would than calculate centers and surface area.

Since for loops are quite slow in python, I have to find another solution. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`center_of_mass` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.11.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.center_of_mass.html) present in `scipy.ndimage.measurements` for the first problem and then use `np.bincount` for the second problem. Because these are in the mainstream libraries, they will be heavily optimized, so you can expect decent speed gains.

Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.ndimage.measurements import center_of_mass
>>> 
>>> a = np.zeros((10,10), dtype=np.int)
>>> # add some labels:
... a[3:5, 1:3] = 1
>>> a[7:9, 0:3] = 2
>>> a[5:6, 4:9] = 3
>>> print(a)
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
>>> 
>>> num_obj = 3
>>> surface_areas = np.bincount(a.flat)[1:]
>>> centers = center_of_mass(a, labels=a, index=range(1, num_obj+1))
>>> print(surface_areas)
[4 6 5]
>>> print(centers)
[(3.5, 1.5), (7.5, 1.0), (5.0, 6.0)]
```

Speed gains depend on the size of your input data though, so I can't make any serious estimates on that. Would be nice if you could add that info (size of a, number of labels, timing results for the method you used and these functions) in the comments.

Comment: Size of `label_2d` is (2046,2046). Timing results very greatly depending on the number of objects present:
num_obj = 476, time = 6.88 sec; num_obj = 564, time = 8.11 sec; num_obj = 708, time = 10.23 sec; num_obj = 909, time = 13.20 sec

With 2 for loops (algorithm described above), execution time is about 2.70 sec, regardless of the number of objects.

Comment: @soccersniper You're telling me that the code you posted originally works consistently faster than using the 2 pre-written functions `bincount` and `center_of_mass`?

Comment: Times written are for searching centers. It takes even longer to calculate surface area.

Comment: No, times written were for my previous code (from the question).

Comment: @soccersniper ah glad to hear that, I was confused when you gave the timing results and could not believe that these were for the 2 functions I mentioned.

Comment: For centers, times are about 30-50 times faster, depending on the number of objects. Improvement is still significant.